# Real time database backup + auto synchronize using C# or Python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, database

I have a SQL server database (Main) in my Computer "A" and an empty Sql server database (backup) in Computer "B". CRUD operations is performed in the database in Computer "A" and also some new data is received in database in Computer "A" through PLC. I want to keep the real-time backup of database in Computer "B" .Computer "A and B" are connected in LAN. Currently after every 5 minute I am truncating the table in database of Computer "B" and again inserting all rows from Computer "A" to Computer "B" but its not a good approach if rows exceed, it will become slow solution. My aim is

> 1) I am aiming for coding approach only (C# or python).
>
> 2) No tools should be used like "dbforgestudio" ,"synchronize tool" etc and it should detect if any change occur in database (CRUD) in Computer "A" and replicate it in Computer "B" automatically.
>
> 3) It should not be database specific ,like this solution would work only with SQL server but not with Oracle database.

Any suggestion or snippets or links using which I could proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

For real-world use you'd want to use a commercial solution, for example AWS and I assume Azure have master - slave db server configurations with automatic failover, as well as continuous backup and snapshot backup solutions.

For a learning experience it might work to try to add your own layer on top of db queries where you transparently do everything twice.

Pseudocode

```
MyDatabaseLayerClass :: run_query ( string, parameter_array )
{
    // db1 and db2 are database connection objects held by this class
    db1. run_query ( string, parameter_array )
    db2. run_query ( string, parameter_array )
    return overall result and set last error states for db1 and db2
}
```

You'd want to add try-catch, decide on how errors should be handled, and so on

Comment: Do I need to store original value in local array and compare it in frequent interval and modify the array if any change occurs?

Comment: Nope, the idea is to "do everything twice".  Instead of making direct calls to your database library, you call a wrapper class that makes the call to db #1 then makes the exact same call to db #2.  So you insert a row in db1, then insert the same row in db2.  You update a row in db 1, then do the exact same update in db 2.  If both databases start out identical and you make the exact same changes then they will end up identical unless there are errors.  This is just for learning though not for production use!

Comment: Now I understood what you are saying. Actually this scenario wont work in my case because though I am performing crud operation but database "A" also receives data from PLC and not only through CRUD... I will edit my question.. Thanks